# Solution for one PC to multiple monitor groups

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a gaming PC with a triple monitor setup and I’d like to build a sim rig with a triple monitor setup powered by the same PC.

I’ve had a good search around and only found KVM switches which is the reverse of what I need and splitters which mean the monitors would end up displaying the same thing. I also have a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti and don’t want to buy another graphics card.

What I’m looking for is to take 3 display port cables to a box, have 6 display port cables coming out (3 to gaming monitors, 3 to sim rig monitors) and a way to switch between them.

Is there anything out there that would allow me to do that? The simple and free solution is just to change the cables around every time but I’d like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

A product similar to this [Bi-directional HDMI Switcher](https://www.walmart.com/ip/441548221) (USD 11.99) can work for your case, but you need 3 of those boxes and have to switch them individually.  From the product description:

> ...|This HDMI Bi-directional Switcher supports One Input to One of the Two Outputs **or Two Inputs to One Output**. In case you want to setup a system where you need to connect two high-definition HDMI sources like a Blu-Ray player or PS4 to a single HDMI display like your big screen LCD **Or you want to switch your single high definition video source easily between two displays**. ...

For a Display Port version, you may use this Angusplay [Bi-directional DisplayPort 1.4 Splitter 8K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089SLDDZZ) (USD 25.77).  As with the HDMI version, you need 3 of them and have to switch them individually.  This product requires an external power source (5V DC via USB cable or power adapter).

Another cheaper option (that works the same way) is this Adking [Bi-directional DisplayPoart 1.4 Splitter 8K](https://www.newegg.com/p/2W4-00MD-00003) (USD 19.99).